# Attachment limitation for REST API

Tags: rest-api, integration, attachment, sharepoint

We are working on doing a Sharepoint integration with Salesforce and a part of this service requires Sharepoint to fetch all attachments including body after a particular date. We were working on building a custom REST API endpoint that sharepoint can call and get all the details. However, as I understand, there is a limitation in terms of the size of response body I can provide which is 3MB. This was confirmed when we tried the call using workbench. The actions failed for attachments (although for sizes above 4 MB).

What is the best way to solve this? One option I thought of was to use the [REST API Blob retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) function. In the documentation, I don't use any limits mentioned and we were also able to make a successful call for attachment with size 13 MB.